# how do I configure csrf in slimphp

Tags: php, model-view-controller, csrf, slim

After running "composer require slim/csrf" to download the csrf dependency files 
My index page is like this:

```js
session_start();
require '/Slim/Slim.php';
require '.../vendor/autoload.php';

//register slim auto-loader
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

//load Twig files after loading Slim
require '../Views/Twig.php';

//initialize Slim to use Twig
$app = new \Slim\Slim(array('view' => new Slim\Views\Twig()));

//add CSRF middleware
$app->add(new \Slim\Csrf\Guard);

//GET route - homepage
$app->get('/', function() use($app) {
   $app->render("index.php");
});
$app->run();
```

But when I load it in the browser, I get this error

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Slim\Slim::add() must be an instance of Slim\Middleware, instance of Slim\Csrf\Guard given, called in C:my-root-folder\index.php on line 27 and defined in C:my-root-folder\Slim\Slim.php on line 1269

Kindly help, I'm a bit new to slimphp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to use Slim 3 middleware with Slim 2. To use `\Slim\Csrf\Guard` you should be using Slim 3 instead.